# Why contents in ModeShape JCR properties are truncated due to Infinispan eviction

Tags: jcr, infinispan, modeshape

We are using ModeShape 4.1.0.Final and Infinispan 6.0.2.Final to build out our content repository. After enabled eviction with maxEntries using singleFile store, I notice that some contents within JCR properties are truncated when number of JCR nodes are exceeded the maxEntries. Is this truncation issue caused by following configuration or a bug in the current release ModeShape 4.1.0.Final?

Here is the ModeShape configuration:

```
{
"name" : "Persisted-Repository",
"jndiName" : "",
"workspaces" : {
    "predefined" : ["otherWorkspace"],
    "default" : "default",
    "allowCreation" : true
},
"security" : {
    "anonymous" : {
        "roles" : ["readonly","readwrite","admin"],
        "useOnFailedLogin" : false
    }
},
"storage" : {
    "cacheConfiguration" : "eviction-test-infinispan-config.xml",
    "cacheName" : "REPOSITORY",
    "binaryStorage" : {
        "type" : "file",
        "directory": "modeshape/content/binaries",
        "minimumBinarySizeInBytes" : 1000000
    }
},
}
```

Here is the Infinispan configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan>
<global>
   <globalJmxStatistics enabled="true"
        allowDuplicateDomains="true" />
</global>
<namedCache name="REPOSITORY">
    <!-- single file store -->
    <persistence passivation="false">
        <singleFile shared="true" preload="false"
            fetchPersistentState="false" ignoreModifications="false"
            purgeOnStartup="true" location="./infinispan/eviction">
        </singleFile>
    </persistence>
    <!-- Look for transaction manager first -->
    <transaction
        transactionManagerLookupClass="org.infinispan.transaction.lookup.GenericTransactionManagerLookup"
        transactionMode="TRANSACTIONAL" lockingMode="OPTIMISTIC" />
    <!-- No more that 10K entries per cache, with LIRS eviction. -->
    <eviction threadPolicy="DEFAULT" maxEntries="10000" strategy="LIRS" />
</namedCache>
</infinispan>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably caused by this bug in Infinispan: [ISPN-4810](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-4810).